# Android encoding incoming IRC socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, encoding, irc

I'm currently working on an IRC-Application for Android and I've notice that when some people write some characters such as åæäøö show up as an unicode replacement glyph (�), this is not always the case but only when some people write.

All IRC-clients for android I've tested seem to have the same dilemma however irssi and Linkinus on my computer seem to handle these just fine and there they show up as the correct character. My guess is that irssi and such clients somehow know what encoding the received message is encoded in and converts it before displaying and I'd like to do something similar in my application but I don't know how.

Edit: Seems as the character is for some reason replaced with 65533 � directly when I take it from the buffered reader. How should I handle this?

Comment: Sounds like you decode with utf-8, but they send with iso8859. The usual approach is to try to decode with utf-8 and then with a fallback encoding. In your case, check for the unicode replacement glyph, if present, fallback to an other encoding.

Comment: How do I check for an unicode replacement glyph in the input stream?

Comment: `mark()` and `reset()` on an underlying BufferedStream.

Comment: Seems as if the BufferedStream is replacing the incorrect characters with char 65533 directly so I'm unable to fix the encoding errors.

Comment: The BufferedStream works on `byte`s, not on `char`s. I don't know how androids `byte` could represend a value > 255, I always belived that a byte has only 8-bit, so replacing something with 65533 should not be possible for the BufferedStream. Note: BufferedStream != BufferedReader.